# Library Management in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, custom, integration

We have numerous document libraries, each one assigned to a different "web" within Sharepoint 2007.  What I'm tasked to do is to upload bulk documents into these "webs" under the document library, then build out a subfolder structure based on the naming conventions of the file(s).

I found the Lists.asmx web service, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do folder management to the detail of being able to traverse a set of folders such as: {client}{year}{document type}... or similar

Does anyone have a readily available solution/article which I can refer to in order to learn how to do folder management?  I seem to have the upload feature to bed, so it's just folder management that I need the assistance on.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jstevensblog.com/post/How-to-Programmatically-Upload-files-and-folders-to-a-SharePoint-Document-Library-and-Update-and-Delete-Files-from-SharePoint-Sites.aspx    --  Check this Link It helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I really, REALLY need to do it through web services.  We don't want to have to manage an entire ERP product within sharepoint just so we can post files.